# SASS + COMPASS - image sprite repeat-y

Tags: css, sass, compass-sass, css-sprites

How to make a sprite from a lot of pictures, and one of them use the "repeat-y"
I see that there is an update about that - https://github.com/chriseppstein/compass/commit/a8241e7924410d0e0f63fca0742e3a01897e4e2c

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use the development version of Compass (see [rubygems](http://rubygems.org/gems/compass/versions/0.13.alpha.4)).

### Install an alpha version of Compass

For install it, you can uses Bundler to not pollute your global environment. In first place, install bundler:

```
$ [sudo] gem install bundler
```

Now, put in your Compass project a file named `Gemfile` with the following content:

```rb
source "https://rubygems.org"
gem "compass", "~> 0.13.alpha"
```

Initialize the Bundler project locally:

```
$ cd my_project/
$ bundle install --path .vendors/bundler
```

You can use the command `bundle exec compass` instead of `compass` for used that specific version of Compass.

### Use the `repeat-y` option of the sprite engine

#### Automatic sprites

If you use the basic import, you have to declare the variable `$<map>-<sprite>-repeat: repeat-y` before the import:

```
@import "compass/utilities/sprites";

$icons-layout: horizontal;
$icons-foobar-repeat: repeat-y;

@import "icons/*.png";
@include all-icons-sprites;
```

In this example, the image named `icons/foobar.png` will be repeated vertically.
**Note that this featured only works with a `horizontal` layout.**

#### Manual sprites

The syntax to declare a `repeat-y` for a sprite is `$<map>-<sprite>-repeat: repeat-y`. Again, only the horizontal arrangement will be viable:

```
@import "compass/utilities/sprites";

$icons: sprite-map("icons/*.png",
                   $icons-layout: horizontal,
                   $icons-foobar-repeat: repeat-y);

.icons {
  background: transparent $icons no-repeat;
}
```